# Efficiency of custom compression algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, compression

I have a compression algorithm idea and I have two questions:

1. Should I deal with it ? Will it be efficient ?
2. How can I optimize it?

Here is the algorithm I've created so far.

```
int i = 0,j, diff, beginIndex = 0;
while(i < tmp.length){
    j = i;
    byte first = tmp[i];
    int total = 0;
    while(j < tmp.length && first == tmp[j] && total < 127){ j++; total++;}

    if(total > 3){
        if(beginIndex != i){
            diff = i - beginIndex;
            packed.put((byte)diff);
            packed.put(tmp, beginIndex, diff);
        }
        packed.put((byte)(0x80 | total));
        packed.put(tmp[i]);
        beginIndex = j; 
    } 

    i = j;

    if(i-beginIndex == 127){
        packed.put((byte)127);
        packed.put(tmp, beginIndex, 127);
        beginIndex = i;
    }
}

if(beginIndex < i){
    diff = i - beginIndex;
    packed.put((byte)diff);
    packed.put(tmp, beginIndex, diff);
}
```

Example input (each letter describes a byte)

```
[A, B, C, D, E, E, B, B, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, B, B, B, B, C, C] = 27 bytes
```

Example output

```
[0x80, A, B, C, D, E, E, B, B, 0x8D, A, 0x84, B, 0x82, C, C] = 16 bytes
```

In examples 0x80 is the packed bit. Represents if following letter will be repeated. 0xFF - 0x80 = 0x7F is the maksimum repeat count (127). So, 0x8D represents following byte will be repeated 0xD (13) times

Any idea optimizing that algorithm? Will it be useful or shall I get rid off the idea?

Comment: You can easily check how efficient it is by comparing the results to an existing well-known algorithm like gzip. But since it's relatively rare that letters repeat in real life data (and existing algorithms already deal with that and much more very efficiently) I don't think this will produce very good results.

Comment: This algorithm is similar to [run-length enconding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding), you can find many info about it on the internet.

Comment: You might use a spelling checker, especially with titles. Compression was fun in the 1980s. Think about your goal before investing a considerable amount of time (and make a note of both).

Comment: The first problem is that it is unable to deal with 0x80 bits occuring in the data. You will need to devise an escape convention, not forgetting a convention to escape the escape. It is nothing more than run-length-encoding and it has already been invented several decades ago.

Answer (score 1):

The question is, what is the purpose of your algorithm?

To invent something really new, you need to check, what was invented before. Read some papers and book about data compression, etc. [Data Compression Explained](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/dce.html) can be good place to start.

If you just want to practice in writing algorithms, it's totally OK. Continue with improving your algorithm, refactoring, speedups, profiling, etc.

If you want your algorithm to be practical, once again, check what was created before. Open source compression algorithms, such as [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) worth studying.

If you want to check, how your algorithm compares to others, run it on some popular test, such as [Silesia Open Source Compression Benchmark](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/silesia.html). That'll give your an intuition where you stand (this might be somewhat disappointing, but don't give up).

Finally, if you want to have fun, just do whatever you want, and don't listen to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

You've invented [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding). Most compression algorithms already incorporate a sort of run-length encoding that will out perform your implementation and work better in more cases. So I wouldn't pursue it if I were you.

If you're interested in data compression in general I highly recommend [Managing Gigabytes](http://www.milkdom.com/uni/Sem05/a4md/docs/Managing%20Gigabytes%3B%20Witten,%20Noffat,%20Bell.pdf) chapters 2 and 6 as a very accessible read.